# error when rerender multiselect picklist

Tags: visualforce, multi-select

can anyone help me solve this error?

the error message : Unsupported attribute disabled in  in Pre_process at line 22 column 101

```
<apex:page controller="preProcessController">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock id="PreProcessPayroll" title="Pre Process Payroll" >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="false" >

             <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Payroll Period" for="listPeriod"/>
                <apex:selectList id="listPeriod" size="1" multiselect="false" value="{!selectedPeriod}" style="width:150px"> 
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!Period}"/> 
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="listEmployee"/>
                </apex:selectList>   
            </apex:pageblocksectionItem>

            <apex:pageblocksectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="All Employee" />
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="ProcessAll">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="listEmployee" />
                </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:pageblocksectionItem>

            <apex:panelGroup id="listEmployee">
                <c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Employee" leftOptions="{!allEmployee}" disabled ="TRUE" rendered="{!ProcessAll != TRUE}"
                                       rightLabel="Selected Employee" rightOptions="{!selectedEmployee}" 
                                       size="14" width="475px"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>               
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton id="RunPreProcess" value="Run Pre Process" action="{!RunPreprocess}"/>           
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Comment: `MultiselectPicklist` in this component do your have attribute name Disabled. Other wise remove it from VF page

Comment: disabled isn't a fucntion?  all i want is disabled my MuliselectPicklist based on my checkbox @TusharSharma

Comment: You can't `directly disbled` it. You can use `rendered attribute` or you need to write custom JS to disable it

Comment: rendered attribute? or js? can gv reference/example about that? @TusharSharma

Comment: Use `rendered="false"` instead of disabled. Also when you want to display use `rendered="true"`

Comment: i tried it, but nothings happen when i tick and untick my checkbox. what i want to achieve is, when i tick my check box, my multiselect is disabled, else when i untick my checkbox, my multiselect can be selected. @TusharSharma
can u gv me suggestion which kind of method could work for my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<apex:pageblocksectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="All Employee" />
                <apex:inputCheckbox id="ProcessAll" value="{!ProcessAll}">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" reRender="listEmployee" />
                </apex:inputCheckbox>
            </apex:pageblocksectionItem>

            <apex:panelGroup id="listEmployee">
                <c:MultiselectPicklist leftLabel="Available Employee" leftOptions="{!allEmployee}" rendered="{! !ProcessAll}"
                                       rightLabel="Selected Employee" rightOptions="{!selectedEmployee}" 
                                       size="14" width="475px"/>
            </apex:panelGroup>
```

Check this code this will hide when checkbox is false and display when it checked. To disable the complete component its not a easy task and we need your component code as well.

Comment: it not work, first : Unknown property 'preProcessController.ProcessAll' , and second error : Unsupported attribute disabled in <c:MultiselectPicklist> in Pre_process at line 22 column 101 @Tushar Sharma

Comment: @Vikolai `ProcessAll` is a boolean property with get set

Comment: ok i already define my public boolean ProcessAll{get; set;}, but still error Unsupported attribute disabled in <c:MultiselectPicklist> in Pre_process at line 22 column 101 @Tushar Sharma

Comment: @Vikolai check my code I have removed it.

Comment: oke it work sir, but it was reverse than what i want haha, now, it was : when checkbox untick(not ticked) my multiselectpicklist hidden, when ticked multiselectpicklist show up. And what i want is when the checkbox ticked, the ListEmployee is hidden, when it unticked(not ticked) the ListEmployee multiselectPicklist show up @Tushar Sharma hehe, i jsut dont understand how to reverse this

Comment: @Vikolai use `rendered="{! !ProcessAll}"` I have also updated my code.